# What causes a singularity as opposed to something of a quantitatively extreme value?

Tags: black-holes, singularities

Something that approaches infinity or is "essentially infinity" (an oxymoron) or is "near-zero" is the very *opposite* of the quality of infinity, and yet explanations tend to use these terms when explaining why black holes occupy an infinitely small volume. What about the creation of black holes makes them infinite on some metrics? I believe this is an obvious question but I have yet to read a single article on black holes/singularities that thinks to answer it.

Comment: Your question is not well defined, because it is based on popular misconceptions. A singularity is a concept from non-physical vacuum solutions. It never forms in a real star collapse. Even aside from this, a singularity contains no mass (it is a *vacuum* solution) and so its density would be zero. However *density* applies to a region of spacetime while a singularity is a coordinate region removed from the spacetime manifold and thus has no density. In particular, a Schwarzschild singularity is a moment of time when time ends. Thus your question cannot be answered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest explanation is that a star above a certain mass collapses to a singularity because there are no known forces that can exert sufficient pressure to stop the collapse.

For example, above the [Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkoff mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_limit), a neutron star collapses because neither the repulsive interaction between neutrons due to QCD nor the quantum degeneracy pressure of neutrons arising from the Pauli exclusion principle is greater than the gravitational force.

Similarly, if quark stars exist, quark degeneracy pressure is weaker than gravity when the mass is above some limit.

When there is no force sufficient to stop a collapse, the collapse continues until a singularity forms and nothing more can be said.

However, this explanation relies on the *known* forces being insufficient. Some physicists think that when we have an accepted theory of quantum gravity, a new repulsive interaction at perhaps the Planck density will prevent a singularity.

Comment: So the gravity pulls the mass together by an absolute value (in which case it would shrink at the same pace until the volume hits zero), rather than a proportional value (in which case the volume would forever stay just as finite and not-infinity)?

Comment: Gravity gets stronger and stronger as the radius decreases, making it collapse faster and faster until it collapses to zero. For example if the Earth shrank to half its radius, the gravity at the surface would increase to $4g$.

Comment: @Smith but is the collapse in proportional terms or absolute terms? If the former, then there is no singularity, and my many confusions about the implications would be cleared.

Comment: Neither of those phrases makes sense to me. I don’t know what they mean in this situation. I don’t understand how you can think a force that gets 4 times stronger when the radius decreases by a factor of 2 is either “proportional” or absolute”. It is “inverse square” (until GR corrections matter).